# Confused about conditional probability with continuous random variables

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are continuous with joint PDF $f_{X,Y}$, so the probability of taking on any individual real value is 0. If I want to compute the probability $P(X > 1.5 \mid Y = \frac{1}{2}) = P(X > 1.5 \cap Y = .5) P(Y = .5) = 0$. But shouldn't I be able to compute the probability I get $X = 1.5$ in the event that I first observe $Y = .5$? Why should it have to be 0?

Comment: You can have a look [there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution#Continuous_distributions). Basically, conditional probabilities are (for the discrete case) a specific case of the continuous setting, which is much trickier (see e.g. the definition of conditional expectation, which is *not* what may expect by only looking at the discrete case). In particular, $\Pr[Y=\frac{1}{2}]$ is $0$ here, but a "corresponding quantity" would be $\Pr[Y \in dy]$ where $dy$ is an infinitesimal interval around $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In essence, you are computing the probability

$$
P(X > 1.5 \mid 0.5-\varepsilon < Y < 0.5+\varepsilon)
$$

in the limit as $\varepsilon > 0$.  With that in mind, the probability you're looking for is given by

$$
P(X > 1.5 \mid Y = 0.5) = \frac{\int_{x = 1.5}^{\infty} f_{X, Y}(x, 0.5) \, dx}
                               {\int_{x = -\infty}^{\infty} f_{X, Y}(x, 0.5) \, dx}
$$

ETA: The limiting probability above (my first expression) is not zero.  Since $P(A \mid B) = P(A, B)/P(B)$, we have

$$
P(X > 1.5 \mid 0.5-\varepsilon < Y < 0.5+\varepsilon)
    = \frac{P(X > 1.5, 0.5-\varepsilon < Y < 0.5+\varepsilon)}
           {P(0.5-\varepsilon < Y < 0.5+\varepsilon)}
$$

We can think of this fraction as the ratio between two volumes: the numerator is the volume under the two-variable PDF over the region between $y = 0.5-\varepsilon$ and $y = 0.5+\varepsilon$, with $x > 1.5$, and the denominator is the volume under that PDF over the region between $y = 0.5-\varepsilon$ and $y = 0.5+\varepsilon$, for any $x$.  In the limit as $\varepsilon \to 0$, those volumes go to zero, but their ratio does not, and is given by the expression above.

Also, I forgot to normalize my integral previously; I've fixed that.

Comment: Sure. But does this probability approach 0 as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: No, it has a non-zero limit, given by the integral in my answer.  I'll elaborate in an ETA in the actual answer.